# How do I show the birthday when I click the names in the list box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using visual c#, windows forms app(.net framework)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> birthdays =
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"Cameron", "4/17/1998"},
            {"Kathryn", "5/7/1997"},
            {"Jason", "1/22/1997"},
            {"Lola", "5/5/1995"},
            {"Wesley", "10/4/1999"}
        };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var element in birthdays)
        {
            namesListBox.Items.Add(element.Key);
        }
    }

    private void namesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = namesListBox.SelectedItems.ToString();
        string birthday = birthdays[name];
        birthdayLabel.Text = birthday;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The term to research is *data binding*

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information - like what GUI framework you are using, what you have tried already and what problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

just a simple change need to make. . . .change the **SelectedItems to SelectedItem**. .. I am pasting the corrected code of **namesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged** event.

```
private void namesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = namesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string birthday = birthdays[name];
    birthdayLabel.Text = birthday;
}
```

Hope it helps you. . .let me know if you have other concerns. .